# How to add motion blur effect to your game in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity and I want to add motion blur visual effect. Which components are required to do that and is any scripting required? If yes, can anyone give an idea?
Also, I need to know how to toggle it through UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your package manager in unity, add Post-Processing.
After that create a new post processing profile in the assets and add motionblur to that. Create a post processing volume in ur scene, set it to global and select the posyprocessing profile. Finally place a post processing layer on your camera and set the layermask to everything.

[Unity Post-Processing Documentation]https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessing-Stack-SetUp.html